# Focus Javascript OpenWindow text

Tags: javascript, html, .net, window, focus

I have a html file that is opened by the following text:

```
onClick="OpenWindow('Images/SupplierHelp.html', 'Large Business Concern',600, 300, 'no')"
```

FULL code block:

```
<td class="LeftAlign" colspan="2">
    <font class="Blackfont" size="1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" NAME="BUSINESSCLASSIFICATION" value="001" onClick="ToggleChk('002'); ToggleDiv(document.getElementById('BUSINESSCLASSIFICATIONDIV'), strBusDiv, true)"/>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="large" runat="server" TABSTOP = "-1" 
                            onClick="OpenWindow('Images/SupplierHelp.html', 'Large Business Concern',600, 300, 'no')"
                            Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#002677" >Large Business Concern</asp:HyperLink> 
            </font>
</td>
```

The html file is formatted like so:

```
Small Business Concern

.... some text paragraph is here

Large Business Concern

.... some text paragraph is here

...etc
```

What I want is to focus the `Large Business Concern` line to the top view of the `OpenWindow`. As of right now, Small business is at the top. Is there a way to focus the string? I thought my `'Large Business Concern'` within the `OpenWindow` would do the trick but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep 'Large Business Concern' text in a div tag and give some id to it.
In your OpenWindow method pass page link as 'Images/SupplierHelp.html#{divid}'

Note: Replace {divid} with id you have given to the div.